# Laravel web socket with pusher does not work

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket, pusher

I am trying to use websocket with pusher for live notification. 
It was working perfect yesterday and suddenly it stopped working

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.domain.com:6001/app/ap1?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

But  when I run `$php artisan websockets:serve` I get this in terminal:

[image: Terminal output]

my bootstrap.js file look like this

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: 'ap1',
cluster: 'us2',
wsHost: window.location.hostname,
wsPort: 6001,
encrypted : false,
disableStats: true,
enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

.env pusher configuration is like this

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=12345
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ap1
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=1234567
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2
```

and broadcasting.php file look like this

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

              'options' => [
              'cluster' => 'us2',
              'encrypted' => false,
              'host' => 'http://example.com/',
              'port' => 6001,
              'scheme' => 'http'

                ],


        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],



'null' => [
        'driver' => 'null',
    ],

],

];
```

App is running on docker container.

Please guide me where I am doing wrong, Any help guys.

Comment: Are you sure that it was working and you didn't change something? Eventually you've reached the pusher free plan limit? Or do you have an enterprise plan?

Comment: I am not using pusher's database, just using its javascript.

Comment: Read the stuff on https://pusher.com/channels. There's a limit for messages and channel with the free plan. This has nothing to do with a database. Or what are you talking about? Here's a tutorial: https://petericebear.github.io/starting-laravel-echo-20170303/. You should eventually read it to learn more about pusher, laravel-echo and websockets. I think you're missing something.

Comment: I don't know about it much about it. But I am not using any app key or secret from pusher as you can see from my .env settings. And about the limit plan, I just logged into my pusher account and just used 4% of daily limit. So I think its not the actual issue here

Comment: Why do you say that you didn't use pusher key and secret? It's stated in your question.